# Elementor form custom webhook returns "error" message

Tags: forms, webhooks, elementor

I'm using Elementor form with custom webhook but every time I submit it, I just get "error" message.

[image]

In my functions.php file I've got Form New Record Action according [Forms API documentation](https://developers.elementor.com/forms-api/).

```
// A send custom WebHook
add_action( 'elementor_pro/forms/new_record', function( $record, $handler ) {

    $form_name = $record->get_form_settings( 'form_name' );

    if ( 'test_form' !== $form_name ) {
        return;
    }

    $raw_fields = $record->get( 'fields' );
    $fields = [];
    foreach ( $raw_fields as $id => $field ) {
        $fields[ $id ] = $field['value'];
    }

    wp_remote_post( 'https://example.com', [
        'body' => $fields,
    ]);
}, 10, 2 );
```

I have "wp_remote_post" there with URL I want to post the form to, but it does not redirect me or something, just returning "error" message.

On Elementor editor I added Webhook action after form submission

[image]

What could be wrong? Thanks

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Comment: @mleister After all I used Redirect action to Wordpress page. I created custom php file in my template and used it for that page. So after form was submitted, I was redirected to that page with all parameters I added to Redirect To URL like this way: https://example.com/my-page/?id_widget=[field id="id"]...

Answer (score 0):

In the last example you need to fill in the wbbhook field at the appropriate URL
[webhookfield](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5nvfv.png)

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar error and it turned out it was a timeout.

By default, the timeout is set to only 5 seconds. This can be increased by using an add_filter in PHP. For example, if you are using make.com as the webhook, you can specify:

```
add_filter('http_request_timeout', function($timeout, $url = '') {
    $start_with = 'https://hook.us1.make.com';
    
    //return is_string($url) && str_starts_with($url, $start_with) // PHP 8
    return is_string($url) && strncmp($url, $start_with, strlen($start_with)) === 0 // PHP 7 or older
        ? 30 // TODO: set appropriate timeout, WordPress default is 5 seconds
        : $timeout; // return unchanged url for other requests
}, 10, 2);
```

EDIT: As pointed out by Juan J, you need to change the $start_with line to match the start of the URL of your webhook. In my case, I was using make.com but your webhook might be on another platform.

To ensure the function is loaded, you need to include it in running PHP code - again, as Juan J suggests, you can add it to the bottom of your wp-includes/plugin.php file.

This was the original issue I logged.

https://github.com/elementor/elementor/issues/20452

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Hi All, you will need to add the function above in wp-includes/plugin.php file at the bottom and then change the `start_with` variable URL with the URL of your webhook. It should resolve the issue. Took me a few hours to figure this out.

Wordpress's default timeout is 5 seconds, so if your webhook takes longer then you will receive this error message. It is stupid.